# How to implement simple search form to be used in conjunction with paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, will-paginate, railscasts, nomethoderror

I am following Ryan Bates' railcasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form
in solving my issue with the search results on a page with will-paginate.

Here he answers the question as to how to solve this problem.  However, I've tried them and haven't had any luck.  From following his second resolution, I get a NoMethod error for "search_conditions" as the result.

The Code:

```
    projects/index.rhtml 
<% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

projects_controller.rb 
def index
  @projects = Project.search(params[:search])
end

models/project.rb 
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

His Answers:

One way is to call the class method "search_conditions" and instead of having it do the find it will just return a conditions array so you could use it in the paginate method.

Course.paginate(:all, :conditions => Course.search_conditions(..))

Another is to call the method "paginated_search" and have it call "paginate" instead of "find".

Lastly you could have the search method accept a block which uses with_scope to set the find conditions. This way you could call "paginate" in that block and the conditions will automatically be applied.

Can someone explain to me how I should go about solving this? I am new to rails and maybe I am just misunderstanding what he is saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Railscast you following is pretty old, lots changed since then. Try to change implementation of `search` method like this:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where 'name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

and something like this in controller:

```
def index
  @projects = Project.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Instead of implementing a system such as Thinking Sphinx, would it be possible to alter the code where a user can search for all instances of strings/columns in the database? e.g. `where 'year LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"` allows me to search for the string "year" (but that string only).  However, I would like for search to look for both "year" and "name" in a single search, with the addition other strings as well.

Comment: @Tony Yes, it is possible: `where 'year LIKE :search OR name LIKE :search', :search => "%#{search}%"`

Comment: If a string that's being searched has a combination of 4 words (e.g. Biology for college students), is there a way where a user can type in 2 of those words (i.e. Biology for), and still have the search appear?  Or does that require something like Sunspot_Rails or Thinking Sphinx?

Comment: @Tony "Biology for" is a substring of "Biology for college students", so in this particular case it will work. It won't work, however, form "Biology college". As far as i know, there is no simple cross-DBMS way to make it work, you need to mess with external search servers or database-specific features (e.g. PostgreSQL includes many awesome features for searching).

Comment: I appreciate all the help! Thank you!